# Accept two integers separated by a delimiter and print their sum

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Hello {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int A = sc.nextInt().split(":");
        int B = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println(A + B);
    }
}
```

If I'm given an input like `1:2` then the output should be `3`. Likewise `54:6` then `60`.

But I'm getting an error. What should I do to achieve that output?

Comment: What does `sc.nextInt().split(":")` return? How can you get from there to two integers? What do you think?

Comment: What error? It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [mre]. Please [edit] your question to include your code, sample input and output, and any error messages. Tell us what you expect to happen as well as what's actually happening. This will help us answer your question better.

Comment: @luk2302 i thougth that i would split the other input..im new to this language

Comment: Does this compile? It shouldn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot call split on an integer, it is meant for splitting a String. Try this:

```
public class Hello {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] numbers = sc.next().split(":");
        int A = Integer.parseInt(numbers[0]);
        int B = Integer.parseInt(numbers[1]);
        System.out.println(A + B);
    }
}
```

Of course some validation would be nice (check if the String contains a colon, if the parts are numeric, etc.), but this should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

At first, read a whole input line into a String variable. Then just split it into two values and cast them to integer.

Code example:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String inputString = sc.nextLine();
String[] splittedValues = inputString.split(":");
int 
    A = Integer.parseInt(splittedValues[0]),
    B = Integer.parseInt(splittedValues[1]); 

System.out.println(A + B);
```

Answer (score 1):

you will need to take input as string and then split your input by : and convert the string to integer and add them.

see example below

````
public class Hello {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        input = sc.next();
        String[] parts = input.split(":");
       if(parts.length > 0) {
           int sum = Integer.parseInt(parts[0])+Integer.parseInt(parts[1]); 
           System.out.println(sum);
       } else{
             System.out.println("Enter number in format example 12:2");
       }
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Hello {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int A = sc.nextInt();
        sc.next().charAt(0);
        int B = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println(A + B);
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think Splitting of two integers is not possible in java(it is possible in python by using the input.split() function) ,for that reason it is better take input as string and split input by using colon(:) operator and convert those input string to an integer and add the both to print the result.
java code:

```
   import java.util.Scanner;
   Public class TwoIntegers
   {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
     Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in());
     String[] two_numbers = s.next().split(":");
     int fir_num = Int.parseInt(two_numbers[0]);
     int sec_num = Int.parseInt(two_numbers[1]);
     int sum=fir_num+sec_num;
     System.out.println("The sum of two numbers is:"+sum);
    }
   }
```